# Expand double lined footer

Tags: header-footer, multicolumn

I have a footer that is shown in the MWE below

Just for illustration I have inserted | between my columns in the footer.
Is it possible to add space around the two |'s so that the three columns
fill up the pagewidth? I want the footer not to be centered, but to fill the width of the page

I tried with `resizebox` multicolumn and a few other options, alas nothing worked.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,fancyhdr,xcolor}

\newcommand{\footertext}{%
\color{gray}\small%
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{r | r | r}
     UiT Norges Arktiske universitet &  Sentralbord 77 54 40 00 & postmotak@uit.no\\
     9037 Troms\o &  Faks 77 64 49 00 & www.uit.no
\end{tabular}}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\footertext}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `tabularx` instead of `tabular`. You won't need \resizebox.

Comment: I also tried to use tabularx, however using `X` makes every column the same width. Which is not desirable as the first column is longer. Nor do I want to guess the correct spacing using something like `{X[2] | X | X}`

Comment: Probably `tabular*`with `\extracolsep` might be useful.

Comment: resizing tables is evil, but the above would work if you removed the space after the table (add `%` at end of line) but `tabular*` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are more satisfied with the following solution using `tabular*`. (Red lines in the screenshot are from the `showframe` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,fancyhdr,xcolor}

\newcommand{\footertext}{%
\color{gray}\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r | r | r}
     UiT Norges Arktiske universitet &  Sentralbord 77 54 40 00 & postmotak@uit.no\\
     9037 Troms\o &  Faks 77 64 49 00 & www.uit.no
\end{tabular*}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\footertext}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: This comment is perfect as I only added the | to show where I wanted to insert extra space.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to get centred vertical rules if you add additional column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum,array,fancyhdr,xcolor}

\newcommand{\footertext}{%
\color{gray}\small\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r >{\vline}c r >{\vline}c r@{}}
     UiT Norges Arktiske universitet &&  Sentralbord 77 54 40 00 && postmotak@uit.no\\
     9037 Troms\o &&  Faks 77 64 49 00 && www.uit.no
\end{tabular*}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\footertext}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use another order of sorting the three rows. In the following MWE I used your table build with `tabularx` and an special column type `C` with sorting order `lCr`.

Please see the following MWE (important code changes are marked with `<========`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} % <===============================================
\usepackage{showframe}% <===============================================

\newcommand{\footertext}{%
\color{gray}\small%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}X} % <===================================
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l | C | r@{}} % <=======================
     UiT Norges Arktiske universitet &  Sentralbord 77 54 40 00 & postmotak@uit.no\\
     9037 Troms\o                    &  Faks 77 64 49 00        & www.uit.no
\end{tabularx}}% <======================================================

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\footertext}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

For me that looks prettier than your solution with `rrr` ...